# Debian 8 Kinetic no packages can be located

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am following Kinetic install on Debian guide (http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Debian) but no packages can be found. The Step 1.4 in the guide returns the same message for all different packages. I am running this on Beagle bone Black.

The http://packages.ros.org is getting hit.

Please see image below with the command-line I am seeing.

[image]

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268249/debian-8-kinetic-no-packages-can-be-located/) by [dnars](https://answers.ros.org/users/31428/dnars/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-08-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You look to be running on armhf. Kinetic only targets Debian Jessie arm64 for binary builds.

At the top of the installation page it calls out supported architectures: http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Debian

We build armhf for Kinetic on Ubuntu Xenial.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2